# Event Hub connection issue with spring boot with service principal

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, spring-cloud, azure-eventhub

When I’m using Service principal in Spring Boot Reactive way of sending events to event hub application is getting error as

```
"amqp:unauthorized-access" error Description "Unauthorized access. 'Send' claim(s) are required to perform this operation. Resource: 'xxx' Sender link was never active. Closing endpoint states.
```

This issue is occurring when we use the service principal, but when ConnectionString is used, it works fine.

Code is using the reactive way Flux sinks and many suppliers are used for sending events, for example:

```
public class EventProducer {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EventProducer.class);
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    @Autowired
    private Sinks.Many<Message<String>> many;

    @Override
    public void send(AppMessage message) {
        log.info(" In  EventProducer Send ");

        Runnable eventTask = () -> {

            try {

                log.info("Going to add message {} to event hub.", message.getMessage().toRawString());
                many.emitNext(MessageBuilder.withPayload(message.getMessage().toRawString()).build(),
                        Sinks.EmitFailureHandler.FAIL_FAST);

            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
               
            }
        };
            executor.execute(eventTask);
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
public class EventProducerConfiguration {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EventProducerConfiguration.class);
    @Bean
    public Sinks.Many<Message<String>> many() {
        return Sinks.many().unicast().onBackpressureBuffer();
    }

    @Bean
    public Supplier<Flux<Message<String>>> supply(Sinks.Many<Message<String>> many) {
        return () -> many.asFlux()
                .doOnNext(m -> log.info("Manually sending message {}", m))
                .doOnError(t -> log.error("Error encountered", t));
    }

}
```

And below are the properties:

```
  cloud:
    azure:
      credential:
        client-id: xxx
        client-secret: xxx
        profile:
          tenant-id: xxx
      eventhubs:
        namespace: xxx

    stream:
      bindings:
        supply-out-0:
          destination: xxx

      function:
        definition: supply

      poller:
        initial-delay: 0
        fixed-delay: 1000
```

Note : roles `AzureEventHub Sender`, `AzureEventHub Owner`, `AzureEventHub Receiver` are working with Connection String. This problem is only with role `service principal`.

Answer (score 0):

From error it seems, service principle doesn't have necessary permissions. But you mention already given roles and permissions. Still could you please kindly recheck if `Azure Event Hubs Data sender` and `Azure Event Hubs Data receiver` roles added?
Below Microsoft Documentation has steps to follow. Kindly cross verify with it if all good with setup.
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-web-pubsub/howto-develop-event-listener.md